# Why can't gcc see a static constexpr array in struct when initializing?

Tags: c++, arrays, static, constexpr

I was building an static constexpr array in a class which references previously defined elements in the same array.  I've tried before without problems, but I've found that gcc is having some issues finding the array's symbol name when it is within a struct.

```cpp
struct Y {
  static constexpr char command_info[8][5][(6)*2] = {
    { 
      { 0, 0 , 0,0},
      { 0, 0 , 0,0},
      { 1, 0 , 1 , static_cast<char>(command_info[0][2] [ (0 +1)*2 - 1 ] + command_info[0][2] [ (0 +1)*2 - 2 ]) , 0,0},
      { 2, 0 , 1 , static_cast<char>(command_info[0][3] [ (0 +1)*2 - 1 ] + command_info[0][3] [ (0 +1)*2 - 2 ]), 1, static_cast<char>(command_info[0][3] [ (1 +1)*2 - 1 ] + command_info[0][3] [ (1 +1)*2 - 2 ]) , 0,0},
      { 1, 0 , 1 , static_cast<char>(command_info[0][4] [ (0 +1)*2 - 1 ] + command_info[0][4] [ (0 +1)*2 - 2 ]) , 0,0},
    },
  };
};
```

The <kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s76Gd48s4)</kbd> shows simplified expanded code, removing other constexpr variables and functions.

Moving this definition outside of the struct works fine.  Is there something wrong with gcc or am I doing something illegal here?

Comment: A more minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/1adc3xPjf  (Seems like gcc doesn't think `command_info` is in scope until after the `;`, but it should be in scope after the `=`).

Comment: Looks like the only workaround is to not put it in the class.  I'll have to put it in a namespace instead and maybe make a reference to it in the class.